# selecting a large number of (specific) rows in file

Tags: perl, unix, sed

I want to select a large number of specific rows from large files.

Using perl, I am creating a command of this style (here printing 2nd and 4th rows):

```
sed -n -e 2p -e 4p $file
```

And launching it using a system() command.

This works fine, except when the number of rows to select from a file becomes quite larger. It currently works with ~10,000 rows, but not with another file where I want to select ~17,000 rows. Is there a limit in the number of arguments that can be passed to sed? Would there be an alternative UNIX tool to use?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Since you already meantion perl: why not perl?

Comment: You could use awk or gawk to do this. Can you describe how sed fails?

Comment: René: you're right it could be done with perl, but I was aiming at one liner, and this would require looping in perl, making a very long one-liner...

Comment: Makes sense almost like calling windows calculator from MATLAB.

Comment: Go up one level. What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish? Show us what these rows look like and why you're selecting them, and i'm sure we'll find you a better solution.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You're right, now I realize that I was stuck into my attempt to use sed. Rethinking the problem and using perl is actually a much cleaner way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one sed command:

use `;` separator instead of several `-e 2p`

```
sed -n -e '2p;4p;12p' file
```

if too long for bash command line

create a temporary file with the same structure inside `2p;4p;12p` and use -f option

```
sed -n -f TemporaryFile file
```

Comment: I am trying to do this exact thing, but having the exact problem that when the list of line numbers is too long (for me more than a few hundred) it errors with `sed: 2: TemporaryFile: command expected`. Assuming I want to do this with sed, any idea why this isn't working? I think it may have to do with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit but I can't figure out how to correctly wrap it in a shell script to bypass the ARG_MAX. Also, the error doesn't specifically say ARG_MAX, so I'm not even sure that's it. Thank you!

Comment: you can also spread the list is several TemporaryFile that are called sequentially `sed -n -f F1 file;sed -n -f F2 file; ...`

Comment: That certainly works, but it’s way slower. Maybe sed just isn’t the right solution, but I’m trying to sample 200k lines from a 200M line file and it’s looking like it’ll take about 5 days. A bit too long.

Comment: jsut not to forget to change the 'p' in a 'q' (print current "line" and exit) and optimize with a '1,X d' in followinf files where X is the last line in previous file.

Answer (score 4):

You must surely have the list of lines that you want somewhere in a file, so let's assume that file is called `lines.txt` and looks like this:

```
1
2
4
7
```

Now, you can do this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{wanted[$0]++;next} FNR in wanted' lines.txt file
```

That says this... `FNR==NR` means the first set of curly braces only applies to the processing of the `lines.txt` file, and when processing that, store in the array `wanted[]` the line number that you want and then move to the next line. The second part, `FNR in wanted` applies to the processing of your second file called `file`. It says, if the line number (`FNR`) is in the array `wanted[]`, then print the line.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a sed limit, but a bash command line lenght limit: it is `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes max (on Linux I have seen values for this value from 131072 to 2621440).

The comment from René Nyffenegger is wise: Perl is the better option for this class of problems, in the *NIX world...

If you describe how you need to select the rows to be extracted (i.e.: from i to j? or a list of specific rows?, some different logic?), it should be easy to give you a code sample...

**UPDATE:**
Below I give you an example for the first use case. Of course, if you give an example of some use case, if a pattern can be found, it should be easy to simplify the solution for the second - more generic - use case...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Print a range of lines from a text file.
# Usage: extract-a-range-of-lines.pl first-line last-line input-file

# use ARGV to verify the number of perl command line arguments
@ARGV == 3 or die "Usage: $0 first-line last-line input-file\n";
my ($first_line, $last_line, $filename) = @ARGV;

open(my $FILE, "<", $filename) or die "Could not read from $filename ($!)"; # open the input file   
# loop through the input file
my $count = 1;
while (<$FILE>) {
  last if ($count > $last_line); # break loop when you get to the last line   
  print $_ if ($count >= $first_line); # print the current line if the line number is greater than first param
  $count++; # increment the line counter
}
close $FILE; # close input file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to use `awk`

```
awk 'NR~"^(2|8|12)$"' file
```

This will print line `2`,`8` and `12`

---

Prints line `2` to `7` and `12`

```
awk 'NR>=2 && NR<8 || NR==12' file
```

or

```
awk 'NR~"^([2-7]|12)$"' file
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually awk also fails at this: "/bin/awk: Argument list too long". I guess I have to use the perl option...

Comment: @jul635 How do you add the argument, can you show some example? If there are some type of pattern, it may be possible to simplify it.

Comment: .@Jotne: No specific pattern unfortunately. The rows to select are based on patterns in another file of same size

Comment: @jul635 so line number comes from an external file? One line pr row?