# how to delete a large number of lines from a file

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I have a file with ~700,000 lines and I would like to remove a bunch of specific lines (~30,000) using bash scripting or another method.

I know I can remove lines using sed:

```
sed -i.bak -e '1d;34d;45d;678d' myfile.txt # an example
```

I have the lines in a text file but I don't know if I can use it as input to sed, maybe perl??

Thanks

Comment: What's the format of the text file?  Massage that data so that it looks like a sed expression...although with 30,000 values you may bump into a limit on the size of the argument to sed.

Comment: Are your files sorted, or can they be sorted?

Comment: Look at this post, it is very similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670650/selecting-a-large-number-of-specific-rows-in-file/26672005#26672005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

```
sed <(sed 's/$/d/' lines_file) data_file
```

```
awk 'NR==FNR {del[$1]; next} !(FNR in del)' lines_file data_file
```

```
perl -MPath::Class -e '
  %del = map {$_ => 1} file("lines_file")->slurp(chomp => 1);
  $f = file("data_file")->openr();
  while (<$f>) {
    print unless $del{$.};
  }
'
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but I like the different options!!

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne'
  BEGIN{ local @ARGV =pop; @h{<>} =() }
  exists $h{"$.\n"} or print;
' myfile.txt lines
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the remove the lines using sed file.
First make a list of lines to remove. (One line number for one line)

```
$ cat lines
1
34
45
678
```

Make this file to sed format.

```
$ sed -e 's|$| d|' lines >lines.sed
$ cat lines.sed
1 d
34 d
45 d
678 d
```

Now use this sed file and give it as input to sed command.

```
$ sed -i.bak -f lines.sed file_with_70k_lines
```

This will remove the lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a text file of the format

```
1d
34d
45d
678d
```

then you can run something like

```
sed -i.bak -f scriptfile datafile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a genuine editor for that, and `ed` is the standard editor.

I'm assuming your lines are in a file `lines.txt`, one number per line, e.g.,

```
1
34
45
678
```

Then (with a blatant bashism):

```
ed -s file.txt < <(sed -n '/^[[:digit:]]\+$/p' lines.txt | sort -nr | sed 's/$/d/'; printf '%s\n' w q)
```

A first `sed` selects only the numbers from file `lines.txt` (just in case).

There's something quite special to take into account here: that when you delete line 1, then line 34 in the original file becomes line 33. So it's better to remove the lines from the end: start with 678, then 45, etc. that's why we're using `sort -nr` (to sort the numbers in reverse order). A final `sed` appends `d` (`ed`'s delete command) to the numbers.

Then we issue the `w` (write) and `q` (quit) commands.

Note that this overwrites the original file!