# GoogleTest: the length of filter expression is too long

Tags: filter, googletest

I have a big set of tests. I want to run a subset of these tests. But this subset includes many tests. So, I use a negative pattern. 
For example:

```
--gtest_filter=TestSet.*-TestSet.Case1:TestSet.Case2:TestSet.Case3:....:TestSet.CaseN
```

The result is that length of filter is too long.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The filter length limit is probably imposed by the operating system on the shell. See [this SO post on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit).

As a workaround, with the positive side effect of improving the structure of your unit tests, you can rename your tests in a way that you can use a simpler filter pattern, e.g. `--gtest_filter="TestSet.Subset*"`

Comment: I try to find out the length problem. I think there is no length limit in GTest. But i'll do some changes base on your advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After thinking twice on the length problem, I think it's probably a shell command limit, not Google Test's thing. Updating answer.