# Clearing content of files recursively in centos Linux

Tags: linux, centos, truncate

I have log files for many websites in a structure like `/var/www/domainname.com/log/access.log` and I am looking to clear their content. I need to find a way to do it in one command, but I do not seem to do it, I have tried with

```
find /var/www/ -type f -name "access.log" -exec cat /dev/null > access.log {} \;
```

But this actually creates a new access.log file copying contents of all access log files of all websites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `truncate` command so that we can truncate all files at once:

```
find /var/www/ -type f -name access.log -exec truncate -c -s 0 {} +
```

- `-c`   ensures that no files are created newly
- `-s 0` sets file size to zero
- `{} +` makes sure all files are passed in one shot (up to [ARG_MAX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19354870/6862601))

---

See:

[UsingFind - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)

Answer (score 2):

How about:
`find /var/www/ -type f -name "access.log" -exec rm {} \; -exec touch {} \;`

Comment: This would need two processes per file.  The `truncate` solution needs only one.

Comment: @codeforester My centos does not have `truncate`, nor does my macOS system. `find`, `rm` and `touch` are available in _any_ system.