# SHA1 checksum of files in large directory and output to text file

Tags: unix, terminal, openssl, xargs

I need to output by file the sha1 checksum into an output file. Several of the files are > than 8gb if that makes a difference and the entire directory contains ~28K files.

This is what I need the output file to look like:

```
SHA1(Windows printed document-1.pdf)= 1c1e2844be6e9ddd995941388b98c12a8b7a1e8d
SHA1(Windows printed document.pdf)= 4ea8a157c5d8d0fc9c38aa6312d120ab425900a0
SHA1(checklist.chk)= c5f9e078578925ef3de1e6075b0777d75296bb8f
...
```

This is the code so far:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 * > ~/Desktop/output.txt
```

This code works great for small files or smallish directories but it's throwing an exception that the argument list is too large when I try to put it into production.

Comment: Probably something like [Bash command line and input limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19354870/608639). You should probably add a script and unroll things a bit. Use `find` and `for each` file found. Maybe something like [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9612090/608639)

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a good place to start. I'll give it a shot and answer my question I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hashdeep -c sha1 -r $DIR` or `find $DIR -print0 -type f | xargs -0 -I {} sha1sum {} > output.txt`