# bash function arguments with embedded newlines

Tags: bash, arguments, newline

I've written a general purpose logger function in bash called **trace()** whose 3rd argument and beyond supposed to club and print as text, preserving any embedded newlines.  But it doesn't.  *I'm looking for an effect similar to echo command that does it as intended (tried below).* 
**Looks like the club-together thing is to blame (${@:3})?**

```
timeStamp() { echo `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%3N %Z"` ;}

trace() {
  lineNum=$1
  traceType=$2
  traceText=${@:3} #Input Parameters 3rd and beyond
  #echo -en "[${lineNum}][$(timeStamp)][${traceType}]: ${traceText}"
  #printf "[%s][%s][%s]: %s\n" ${lineNum} "$(timeStamp)" ${traceType} "${traceText}"
  printf "[${lineNum}][$(timeStamp)][${traceType}]: ${traceText}"
}
```

**Trials/Output**:

```
$ trace $LINENO ERR "This is
a multiline
text
that's supposed to go
upto 5th line"
[342][2017-08-04 00:42:02:062 EDT][ERR]: This is a multiline text that's supposed to go upto 5th line

$ echo "This is a
> multiline text
> that's supposed
> to go
> upto 5th line"
This is a
multiline text
that's supposed
to go
upto 5th line
```

Comment: Have you tried `printf "[${lineNum}][$(timeStamp)][${traceType}]: ${@:3}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comment, you can also rewrite `trace()` altogether to include a *command substitution* for `date` and simply use the *positional parameters* in the `printf` *format string*. For example:

```
trace() { 
    printf "[$1]$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%3N %Z")][$2]: ${@:3}"
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ trace 123 "some error" "this
is my
multi-line
text
"
[123]2017-08-04 01:01:29:765 CDT][some error]: this
is my
multi-line
text
```

**note:** there is a limit on the number of *positional parameters* that can be passed, so if your multi-line text exceeds the limit, `trace` will not work. See: [**Bash command line and input limit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit)

Comment: That won't work right if there are more than 3 arguments, because arguments past `$3` will be treated as separate arguments to `printf`, and unlike `echo` it doesn't just mash its arguments together (it does something considerably more complicated). Switching to `${*:3}` (which mashes all the arguments together before passing them to `printf`) would work.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that is a good point. It is a rather screwy way to handle reproducing multi-line text. You would think the preference would be to pass it on `stdin` and `while read -r ...` the input.

Comment: Thanks both @GordonDavisson & DavidCRankin. I'll try the unambiguous ${*:3} option and keep you posted.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is indeed in `traceText=${@:3}`. Normally, `$@` is equivalent to `$1 $2 $3...` (and `${@:3}` to `$3 $4 $5...`), and since it isn't in double-quotes, each of those goes through word splitting and wildcard expansion. But in the case of `var=$@` it can't assign multiple values to `var`, so the word splitting and wildcard expansion gets suppressed... but apparently not completely. It's apparently doing enough word splitting to convert newlines to spaces.

I'm not clear if this is a bug or not; IMO it's a situation that doesn't really make sense because of the conflict between `$@` (treat each parameter as a separate item) and `=` (which can only assign one value). IMO what you should be using is `traceText="${*:3}"`, which is unambiguous -- the double-quotes explicitly suppress word splitting and wildcard expansion, and the `$*` means take all the arguments stuck together with spaces (or whatever the first character of `IFS` is).

In my testing (with bash v3.2.57), all of these work as expected:

```
traceText=${*:3}
traceText="${*:3}"
traceText="${@:3}"
```

The only one that gives weird results is with `@` and without double-quotes.

Comment: So having quotes around, solved my problem.  So I ended up using "${@:3}"