# Can i detect in anyway if a string will make a json syntax error in PHP or Python

Tags: php, python, arrays, json

I'm trying to send an array (with a length of 45,000) from PHP to Python and back.

From PHP to Python:

```
$a = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python2.7 script.py "'.$b.'" '.escapeshellarg(json_encode($array)));
```

From Python to PHP:

```
B = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print json.dumps(B)
```

And in the PHP code:

```
$output = json_decode($a);
$arrfinal = array_values($output);
```

Hope this is make sense..

So i try to run it for 3700 rows of the array and it works just fine.

if i try to run it for more than 3700 rows it gives me a syntex error (from `json_last_error()`)

So my question is, Is there anyway I can check if string will make a json syntex error if will be "changed" to json format before it "change"?

Thanks!

P.S already try changing everything to UTF-8 after hours of searching online..

Sorry for my English..

Comment: Would wrapping `json.loads` in a `try..except` block work for you?

Comment: If you have a string that may or may not be valid JSON, you can put `json.loads()` inside a try/except block.  If you get a `ValueError` exception, then it wasn't valid.

Comment: But I'm creating the Json from an array (that being created in the Python). So if I'm going to wrap it with try except the all array is not going to be vaild because one of the rows..

Comment: JSON is either valid or it isn't. If one row is bad then the entire JSON is bad.

Comment: I would suggest doing a base64 encoding of your JSON before sending it.

Comment: @ryantxr I try to chage everything to base64, but the text (in base64!!) still create a bad Json.. How is it possible??

Comment: @ryantxr maybe i can check for this type of "bad" strings  from the mysql? at this point i will try anything!!

Comment: You need to divide and conquer. PHP should be able to create JSON and read that JSON it produced. First make sure that PHP can generate the JSON and read the JSON it created. 
After that, make sure that python can decode the JSON it received.

Comment: What's the size (in bytes) of your JSON (encoded array)? Maybe you're hitting the [limits of program arguments length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit). What system are you running this on?

Comment: @randomi Seems like 3700 is my limit. Will check the post thanks!