# Sending data from python to c++ as parameters or file?

Tags: python, c++, visual-c++

I have two programs. My main program is in python and I have another one in c++ because I have to connect to a machine and the only way I can use this machine is a dll/lib made with c++ that the constructor gave me.

In my python, I'm getting from a database thousands points and I'm doing some operations on them and those points are stocked in differents array in a class.

Now, I need to send thoses points to the c++ program and I was wondering how. I can send them as parameters to the main of the c++ program but the command line is then too long and I think even if it wasn't too long, this would be a really bad practice (If someone can explain a little why, that would be cool!).

Actually, I'm thinkinng to generate a file with all the coordonates in this file in my python program and send it too the c++ but I have to parse it then in c++. 
Is it a good way to do it? Or maybe an other solution would be better?

Comment: btw [data is already plural](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2010/jul/16/data-plural-singular)

Comment: That's right. I'm going to correct it. Thanks and sorry for my english ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ways:

1. Use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) with `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and write the data one per line, parsing it on the C++ side
2. Use temporary files, either text files or other files
3. Use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) and load the C++ part as shared library and then call into the C++ functions from Python directly
4. Use Python's [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to encode your data from Python into C structs, which avoids the string formatting and string parsing -- this can be combined with any of the three above: `subprocess.Popen` (read binary data from `stdin` in C++), temporary files (open in binary mode) or `ctypes` (pass a pointer to the struct directly to the library function)

As to the question why passing arguments on the command line is problematic, there are limits imposed by the OS, e.g. [getconf ARG_MAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351/104704).

Comment: I read somewhere that the limit or arguments was often 4096. But, for example, if I know that I will always have like 1000 arguments, is that a reason to parse the command line each time?

Comment: AFAIK the limit is in bytes, not in number of arguments. So if you have 100 arguments, 4096 gives you ~ 39 bytes per argument (assuming 1 space as separator, and calculating using (4096-99)/100, not taking into account the command length itself).