# Delete elements caught from a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple `.mkv` files in `eng.md` which listed by codes

```
    $ grep -i 'mkv' eng.md
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep4.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep5.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep6.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep7.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/._The.Adventure.of.English.Ep4.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep8.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/._The.Adventure.of.English.Ep8.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/._The.Adventure.of.English.Ep5.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/._The.Adventure.of.English.Ep6.mkv
```

I decide to remove mkv files with pipeline methods and try

```
$ rm < grep -i 'mkv' eng.md
-bash: grep: No such file or directory
```

Try alternatively

```
$ grep -i 'mkv' eng.md | rm 
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
grep: eng.md: No such file or directory
```

How to resolve such a problem?

Comment: did you try xargs:  `grep -i 'mkv' eng.md | xargs rm`

Comment: This would also delete files named `foo/bar/mkv/x.txt` and `blablabla.MKV`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this, (unless it's some huge list of files that [exceeds the command line maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351/6136214)):

```
rm $(grep -i mkv eng.md)
```

Comment: It maybe should be noted that this works unless there are "too many" mkv files, while the solution posted by @shirish works for any number of mkv files.

Comment: and also I would recommend to use `\.mkv$` for the grep pattern who knows if there is `mkv` in the file name of some records

Comment: Yes, and the `-i` should be dropped. I put everything together in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since neither of the comments really gave a solution which works for every situation, I propose here an approach slightly modified from what shirish suggested in his comment:

```
grep '[.]mkv$' eng.md | xargs rm
```