# How can I run cloud shell commands from Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, google-cloud-shell

I've been trying to automate my GCP dataflow system. Uncompressed txt files are loaded into the pipeline much faster as compared to compressed gzip files because of some parallelization issue. So, I have to first convert my gzip files into txt files using gsutil commands in google interactive shell:

```
gsutil cat gs://nse-fao-data-test/FAO* | zcat |  gsutil cp - gs://nse-fao-data-test/uncomp/hello9.txt
```

Now to automate the system, I try to run this gcloud shell in my local by giving OS command in python and call it every time before my pipeline begins:

```
import os
import subprocess

def uncompress(in_file = 'gs://nse-fao-data-test/FAO*',out_file="gs://nse-fao-data-test/uncomp/uncompressed.txt"):
    subprocess.call("gsutil cat {0} | zcat |  gsutil cp - {1}".format(in_file,out_file))
    
def openShell():
    os.system("gcloud cloud-shell ssh --authorize-session")
```

While the openShell command works and starts gcloud shell in my local, but the uncompress does not execute. Is there any way I can automate command present in uncompress() function without writing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` runs in its own environment, when that command you call ends, it will exit. so your authorize-session is gone after the call.

You may checkout using `subprocess.Popen` instead and run multiple commands maybe.

There is a [good answer on how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51111906/1562772)

and link to subprocess explanation states: "This module intends to replace **several older modules and functions**"  with [explanation on](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) how to replace os.system commands

**Edit**: For specific use case on gcloud cloud-shell ssh, it opens up a new "interactive" session which you cannot pass commands programmatically, instead you may use --command=XXX argument while running it

```
To run a remote command in your Cloud Shell, run:
$ gcloud cloud-shell ssh --command=ls
```

For windows putty you need to allow batch for putty as it is asking entering Return key.

Comment: I get a "Access granted. Press Return to begin session." when running gcloud cloud-shell ssh ... how can I avoid this?