# How many object files can I pass to a linking task?

Tags: linker, loader, toolchain, compiler-specific

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351/1737973) for a vanilla case of Bash on GNU/Linux, but what about other shells, other operating systems and other compilers?

Answer (score 2):

> How many object files can I pass to a linking task?

Depends on the linker you use.

When using binutils `gnu-ld` or `gold`, you can use Windows-style response file, which allows you to bypass command line length limits and pass as many arguments as you need:

```
echo "foo.o bar.o baz.o ... -lc" > args
gcc main.o -Wl,@args  # there is no limit on how big args file is.
```

Comment: My question is how many before a lib solution becomes faster.

Comment: @Lothar If you have a question, ask it (instead of commenting here).