# Shell, copy files with similar names

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I would like to copy a series of similar files from the current directory to the target directory, the files under the current directory are:

```
prod07_sim0500-W31-0.2_velocity-models-2D_t80_f0001_ux.hst
prod07_sim0500-W31-0.2_velocity-models-2D_t80_f0001_uz.hst
prod07_sim0500-W31-0.2_velocity-models-2D_t80_f0002_ux.hst
prod07_sim0500-W31-0.2_velocity-models-2D_t80_f0002_uz.hst
prod07_sim0500-W31-0.2_velocity-models-2D_t80_f0003_ux.hst
prod07_sim0500-W31-0.2_velocity-models-2D_t80_f0003_uz.hst
```

Where `sim` is from `sim0001` to `sim0500` and `f` is from `f0001` to `f0009`. I only need `f0002`, `f0005` and `f0008`. I write the following code:

```
target_dir="projects/data"

for i in {0001..0500}; do
    for s in f000{2,5,8}; do
        files="[*]$i[*]$s[*]"
        cp $files target_dir
    done
done
```

I am very new to Shell, and wondering how to write the `$files="[*]$i[*]$s[*]"$`, so that it could match only the `f0002`, `f0005` and `f0008`. The reason why I also use `for i in {0001..0500}; do` is that the files are too large and I would like to make sure I could access some completed ones (for example, including all sim0001) in the beginning.

Edit: changed `for s in f0002 f0005 f0008; do` to `f000{2,5,8}`.

Comment: What about `cp *sim0[0-5][0-9][0-9]-*_f000[258]_* /target/` ?  Fill in globs as required, of course...  Might barf if you have more files than [ARG_MAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351/1072112), but I don't see the need for loops. (Yes, I know this also matches sim0000.. If that's a concern, split it into two commands. Still less typing and headaches than nested loops.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [globbing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and a bit different [quoting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes):

```
cp *"$i"*"$s"* "$target_dir"
```

Not storing this in a variable is intentional - it's faster and it's safe. If you end up with such a large list of files that you start running into system limits you'll have to look into `xargs`.

Comment: Maybe emphasize that both quoting the wildcard and embedding it in square brackets individually turns the wildcard into a literal `*`. You have to remove both the quotes and the square brackets before you get an actual wildcard.

Comment: Both of those (and more) should be very well explained by the linked articles.