# OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: 'php' - Python 3.6

Tags: python, linux, shell

I want to call PHP script from my Python script

I have this code

```
subprocess.run(['php', "script.php", long_string], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but I am getting error

```
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: 'php'
```

I have read online threads that I should always use `subprocess.run` for Python 3+

I have also tried

```
subprocess.run(['ulimit', '-s', 'unlimited', 'php', "script.php", long_string], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

But then I get

```
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'
```

My string is `141,664 characters = 141,706 bytes` and that can get larger too

What should I do? How to surpass length error for my Python script?

My `uname -a` output is

Linux mani 2.6.32-042stab123.9 #1 SMP Thu Jun 29 13:01:59 MSK 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I edited a bit to make it more obvious that your last item is an actual long string. Does the same command work in a terminal (outside python)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak its this command https://pastebin.com/M8ZdJXtT and it doesnt execute in shell

Comment: You should probably add details about your OS as this is bound to be specific to it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak `uname -a` outputs `Linux arik 2.6.32-042stab123.9 #1 SMP Thu Jun 29 13:01:59 MSK 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit) doesn't offer workarounds... can you change from command line args to stdin?

Comment: @AndrasDeak sorry for lack of knowledge, how do I change to stdin? is that something to do in the subprocess.run code in Python side?

Comment: Sorry, I was too terse from mobile. I meant rewriting the php script so it takes the data from stdin instead.

Comment: Check this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45583/argument-list-too-long-how-do-i-deal-with-it-without-changing-my-command

Comment: @AndrasDeak it worked, thanks for pointing me to right direction

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Andras Deak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak) for pointing me to right direction, solution was to to send and read data from STDIN instead of Command Line

### WORKING SOLUTION

Python code

```
subprocess.run(['php', "script.php"], input=long_string.encode("utf-8"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

PHP code

```
//to receive data from our Python scrapers
if (defined('STDIN')) {
    $post = json_decode(fgets(STDIN), true);
}
```

### Old code (not working)

Python code

```
subprocess.run(['php', "script.php", long_string], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

PHP code

```
//to receive data from our Python scrapers
if (defined('STDIN')) {
    $post = json_decode($argv[1], true);
}
```