# How to use base64 encoded image as an argument?

Tags: shell, docker, ubuntu, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use the base64 encoding of an image as a flag when I run my program. Im getting back: **Argument list too long**

I am on a Ubuntu 16.04 Docker image on a mac.

```
$ ./myProgram -input "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA [...]"
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit

Comment: The image can't be bigger than 96kb (Linux) or 192kb (mac), because this would base64 encode to the argument limit of 128kb/256kb

Comment: Can you read it through stdin instead?  That would avoid any issues with the size of the argument.

Comment: save it to disk and pass the path instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accepting it as an argument, I would suggest you read it from standard in instead.

```
$ base64 someImage.jpg | ./myProgram
```

If this program is a shell script, you can save standard in into a variable with something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

MY_BASE64_IMAGE_INPUT=$(cat -)
# do something with that info
echo $MY_BASE64_IMAGE_INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a length limit of a single command. This is your program... It should be easier in every way to send the name of the file as the argument to your program which would then read the desired information from the file. You could cat the contents of the file into a variable (if you really want it as a variable). It may be more conventional if you passed the contents of the file to your program via the standard input stream.