# How long can a bash command be?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, buffer

I remember working on an old midrange in `ksh` and dynamically building commands that ran over the 2kb I had available in the buffer.

I recently came upon an issue where one possible easy fix might create very long commands with lots of long arguments. A coworker asked what the limit was in modern `bash`, and it occurred to me that I have no idea. Searches all seem to get sidetracked into the number of lines in the history buffer, but that's not relevant here.

So I ran some tests (please check my logic here...)

```
time echo $( printf "%01024d" $( seq 1 $max ) ) | wc -c
```

I ran a few simple tests with great success. Even on my laptop's `git bash` emulation, if I run this with `max=32` I get

```
$: time echo $( printf "%01024d" $( seq 1 $max ) ) | wc -c
32769

real    0m0.251s
user    0m0.061s
sys     0m0.215s
```

That's an `echo` followed by 32 1kb strings as space-delimited arguments, piped to `wc -c` reporting an appropriate number of bytes received, in about a quarter second. Needless to say I was pleased and surprised, so I started doubling `max` looking for the cap... and failed. Look at this.

```
max=40960
$: time echo $( printf "%01024d" $( seq 0 40960 ) ) | wc -c
41944065

real    0m10.985s
user    0m4.117s
sys     0m7.565s
```

Eleven seconds to process, but that's a single command line of 41MB, successfully created, loaded, executed and parsed.

Holy crap... What's the upper end of this spec???

And/or is there some reason this test isn't a good proof that I could build an almost arbitrarily long command?

Comment: [This](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) might be relevant here.

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate, thanks for the link. Relevant takeaway - the problem is less about line length than number of arguments. On my laptop `getconf ARG_MAX` returns `32000`, but I can set `max=256000` and `/bin/echo $( seq 1 $max ) | wc -w` gives me `256000`, though at `512000` I get `0`...

Comment: Since you agree it's a duplicate, I'll go ahead and vote to close as such. Either way, glad you found the answer you needed.

Comment: Yep, Thanks! (I'm easy, lol)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A short answer for the main question is:

The limit for the length of a command line is not imposed by the shell, but by the operating system. This limit is usually in the range of hundred kilobytes.

Comment: This seems sensible - why the downvote? (Yes, I actually am curious about the spec, but this is still relevant.)

Comment: This appears to be a verbatim quote of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351/3307686), which is not even your own answer. Instead of reposting someone else's answer as your own, you should just comment and point out that the question is a duplicate, and link to the existing answer.

Comment: This is my first answer to a question i just started using this website. So it's my bad if i did it the wrong way

Comment: @RakanAjlouni That's understandable. In the future, please provide a comment saying "possible duplicate of ..." and provide a link to the existing answer. Also, copying someone else's words verbatim without  attribution is generally frowned upon, not only on StackOverflow, but pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Indeed that's true, how can i exactly provide a hyper link like you did "this answer"?

Comment: See here: [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).