# How to limit what the Linux Teminal prints by defaults (prompt)? (i.e. number of subfolder)

Tags: bash, terminal, terminator

**Context:**

The problem comes from the work folder location: if I should work in a subfolder of a subfolder of a subfolder et cetera... The command line of the shell bask in Linux is so long that can use two lines to be correctly printed.

**Question:**

Is there a way of showing only the last (or the few last) working subfolder?

**Example:**

What is actually printed:

```
user@user-pc:~/Documents/robotic_arm/Monitoring/difference/develop/component/example/subfolder/subexample/module$
```

What I would love to see:

```
user@user-pc:~/.../subexample/module$
```

**More Info:**

- Xubuntu 16.04
- `Terminator` is used instead of the default "Linux Terminal Emulator"
- I had a look [on this Stackoverflow's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit) but it is for the input and not for the default line printed by the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why but the previous answer does not work on my machine. However, an alternative solution that works fine is:

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=N
```

where `N` is the number of subfolders you want to see.

**Example:**

```
user@user-pc:~/Documents/robotic_arm/difference/develop/component/ $ PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2
user@user-pc:~/.../develop/component/ $
```

The solution was suggested by one of the answers above [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PROMPTING section of `man bash`. You configure the prompt by setting PS1, and I suspect your current setting is something like this:

```sh
$ echo $PS1
\u@\h:\w\$
```

If you change it to

```sh
$ PS1='\u@\h:\W\$ '
```

it will only print the basename of the current working directory.

Comment: `echo $PS1`

`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$`

Comment: Yes, that's with some colors added. You need to modify it so that `\w` is replaced with `\W`.

Comment: Put the change in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` with `export PS1=...`

Comment: it does not work and now: `echo $PS1`

`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \W\a\]$ ...`

Comment: I have just found another solution and used as another alternative answer. Can be the use of `Terminator` my problem with your proposal?