# unknown output from aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm setting environmental variables for the AWS via cli. I installed the aws-cli bundle in zip.
After setting AWS creds I run: `eval $(aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-2)`

from which I'm getting this output I don't understand:

eval: eyJwYXlsb2FkIjoiaXB2b.....: File name too long

Can anyone advise what's happening here ?

**Edit:**

```
then
    curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
    unzip awscliv2.zip
    sudo ./aws/install
    unzip awscli-bundle.zip
    ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
    export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
    export AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=''
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''
    eval $(aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-2)
    export TAG=$GITLAB_BRANCH
    export REPO=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

aws-cli version:  aws-cli/2.1.19 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.8.0-38-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off

`aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-2 --no-include-email` supposed to work as an alternative which just gives out the "help" output.

Comment: why do you `eval` the result of `aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-2`?

Comment: By the way: you posted live credentials of your container registry, I edited them out for now and flagged for mod intervention to actually remove them from the edit history.

Comment: Because it should return True or False when checking my creds.

Comment: You should (if anything) pipe the result of the ecr command into `docker login --username AWS --password-stdin pathToYourECR`

Comment: That is not close to anything this command does, it returns credentials and then you do something with those credentials, `eval` has no place in this.

Comment: @luk2302  I didn't mind including it because it wasn't full output hence useless.

Comment: @luk2302  Well, I added a snippet I'm working with. The `eval` command used to work just fine. It's not working anymore and I need to find out what went wrong.

Comment: I remember the `eval` command returned `Login Succeeded` in the past. Now it's returning the lengthy output ending "Filename too long".

Comment: @wood from the error it seems like realted to bash command line input limit. This question [Bash command line and input limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351/2246345) has few configs you can check. Is this inside a container?

Comment: As I said: the result should be piped into docker login: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html