# How to run regression using makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, tcsh

I have tcsh shell. I want to compile once which is `VCS` and then run multiple testcases using `SIMV`. Earlier for single test `VCS = vcs -sverilog -timescale=1ns/1ps \    +acc +vpi ..` and `SIMV = ./simv +UVM_VERBOSITY=$(UVM_VERBOSITY) +UVM_TESTNAME=$(TESTNAME) ${vcs_waves_cmd} -l $(TESTNAME).log` were defined as constants.

I have to replace $(TESTNAME) by looping on an array.I tried as below by switching to bash but ultimately it is causing other failures such as `make clean`not working.

```
TESTS = ext_reg_write_read reg_write_read 
regress: $(TESTS) 
  $(VCS)\ 
  for t in $(TESTS); do\
./simv +UVM_VERBOSITY=$(UVM_VERBOSITY) +UVM_TESTNAME=$$t ${vcs_waves_cmd} -l $$t.log;\ 
done
```

Also I would like to add export shell command `export SHELL = /bin/csh -f`

My question is similar to following – [Implementing `make check` or `make test`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927676/implementing-make-check-or-make-test)

I have used @J. C. Salomon 's answer to make this code

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your makefile snippet. I tried but you reverted a bunch of it in ways that I don't believe can be correct.

Comment: What error *exactly* are you getting? Is make running `tcsh` for your rules? I would expect it to run `/bin/sh` unless you've told it otherwise.

Comment: Why is it running three times? You only have two arguments in `TESTS`.

Comment: The formatting is still off, you need to show us your code exactly. Edit your question, paste in the real code, select it, hit ctrl-K.

Comment: Sorry @Etan Reisner and  tripleee . I hope the formatting is correct now. But also I am not able to see the error now().Earlier it was saying like t is not defined in the third pass. I also expect it to run for two times only.

Comment: So formatting the code correctly has solved the problem?

Comment: Sorry I was not getting the difference between the shell earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `export SHELL = /bin/csh -f` which I was changing to `export SHELL = /bin/bash -f`.

But finally `SHELL := /bin/bash` works as answered in [How can I use Bash syntax in Makefile targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets?rq=1) by @derobert